# Online radio with PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, ajax, audio, mp3

I am working on a project where users can listen to songs that they have uploaded to the server.  The audio player remains on the extreme bottom left corner of every page and the player has play, pause, volume and next/previous buttons.  I know how to stream audio files but I don't know how to customize the audio player.

Here is what I have tried for streaming the audio files, but the audio player is not customized here and the player also doesn't have any next/previous buttons...

```
<?php
  $file_name = 'mem/1/sound/sample.mp3';

  header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
  $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
              'method' => 'GET',
              'protocol_version' => 1.1,
            )
          );
  $context = stream_context_create($opts);
  $stream = fopen($file_name, 'rb', FALSE, $context);
  $metadata = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
  $data = stream_get_contents($stream);
  print($data);
  fclose($stream);
?>
```